# Prevent the child window from moving together with its parent

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

After using SetParent, the now child window moves together with its parent. How is it possible to prevent the child from following the parent in its movements?
C++ in VS2012

Comment: It's time to make up your mind. Do you want a child window, or don't you?

Comment: Well it's due to the limitations in a 1999 game (I'm making a DLL extension to work with windowed mode), however I've already found a way that doesn't require child to be still. So this question is now closed. But thanks to everyone here for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) style, that is intended for floating things. And [CCS_NOPARENTALIGN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the other styles around it.